# Order_ID could refer to more than one table in the FROM clause of the SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

**ERROR Message**

> Order_ID could refer to more than one table in the FROM clause of the SQL statement

```
SELECT Customer_ID, o.Order_ID, o.Order_Date, p.Product_Description, p.Product_Finish 
FROM Order_T AS o, Order_Line_T AS ol, Product_T AS p
WHERE o.Order_ID=ol.Order_ID
AND ol.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
AND ol.Ordered_Quantity > 3
ORDER BY Order_ID;
```

I keep getting an error stating Order_ID could refer to more than one table in the FROM clause of the SQL statement, can someone help me with this I have no idea whats wrong.

Comment: What DBMS did you use? oracle or ms-access?Please put you are using sql statement.

Comment: I am using MS-Access

Comment: Try to become more specific in which column should use to order the SQL statement.  `o.Order_ID` or `ol.Order_ID`

Comment: SELECT Customer_ID, o.Order_ID, o.Order_Date, p.Product_Description, p.Product_Finish

Comment: I had a select statement above it not sure why something else got posted but do you mean with that?

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM Order_T AS o, Order_Line_T AS ol, Product_T AS p
WHERE o.Order_ID=ol.Order_ID
....
```

looking at the above query, you can see that there are at least two columns `Order_ID` in 2 tables:

- o.Order_ID
- ol.Order_ID

There is also `Order_ID` column in this clause `ORDER BY Order_ID;` without an alias. The database doesn't know which order_id column should use here - o.Order_ID or ol.Order_ID , and reports an error.
Just use an alias in the order by clause: `ORDER BY o.Order_ID;`, this should fix the problem.

Comment: Ohh gotchu that makes more sense now, but it did give me another syntax error saying there is a missing operator in o.Order_ID=ol.Order_ID statement and to use AND

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `JOIN`.

While `WHERE` clauses can be acceptable, it is preferred in Access to use the `ON` keyword.

Additionally, Access requires parentheses around multiple joins within the same statement.

Try:

```
FROM (Order_T AS o INNER JOIN Order_Line_T AS ol ON o.Order_ID=ol.Order_ID) 
INNER JOIN Product_T AS p ON ol.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
WHERE ol.Ordered_Quantity > 3
ORDER BY o.Order_ID;
```

Comment: I see I think it was me missing the inner join but it worked now thank you!